# Elementary embeddings,V,set theory,L,cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I would like to make clear some properties of $j,M,L$ and $V$ in ZFC.

let $j:V \to M$ denote a (nonidentity) elementary emedding and $M$ a transitive $\in$-model of ZFC.Is there an example of moderately large cardinal, whose existence in $V$ ensures that for $M=L$,such $j$ exists? At best, which LC is equivalent to this assertion?

Next, what is some inutition (good explanation) behind the fact, that taking $M$ too large prevents *existentce* of such a $j$? 
One would say, that taking $M$ larger, then V is more easily embedded into it.
Is it true that, if such a $j$ exists for some $M$,then it exists for $M=L$?

Answer (score 6):

You've asked a bunch of questions; let me give an overview of the answers. For more detailed information, you should look at Jech's book on set theory, which contains a ton of excellent information on large cardinals.

So let's start with an elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$. It's easy to see that, if $j$ is nontrivial, then there is some least ordinal $\kappa$ such that $j(\kappa)>\kappa$; this is called the *critical point* of $j$.  Now, if such a $j$ exists, we can consider the following family of subsets of $\kappa$: $$\mathcal{U}_j=\{X\subseteq\kappa: \kappa\in j(X)\}.$$ You can check that $\mathcal{U}_j$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $j$, so $\kappa$ is measurable.

In the other direction, if $\kappa$ is measurable, then let $N=\prod_\kappa V/\mathcal{U}$ be the ultrapower of the universe mod a measure $\mathcal{U}$ on $\kappa$. $N$ is well-founded, so we may take its Mostowski collapse; this is a class $M\subset V$ which is an inner model. Composing the ultrapower embedding with the Mostowski collapse gives an elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$; this embedding is nontrivial, with critical point $\kappa$ (a good exercise).

So we have: **The existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into $M$, for some inner model $M$, is equivalent to the existence of a measurable cardinal.**

*Note: the fact that the thing we're embedding is "$V$" itself is crucial here. For much cheaper we can get a nontrivial elementary embedding of $L$ into $L$ - this just takes $0^\#$.*

---

Now moving on to your second question: Is there a  large cardinal which implies that there is a nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ into $L$, specifically? The answer turns out to be *no* - the existence of such an embedding is inconsistent! For, if there were one, $V$ would contain a measurable cardinal (by the above), so by elementarity, $L$ would have to contain a measurable cardinal. But that's not possible. This was proved by Scott, and is a good exercise: show that if $j: V\rightarrow M$ is the elementary embedding coming from a measure on $\kappa$, then $(2^\kappa)^M\supsetneq 2^\kappa$, and so $M$ is a strictly smaller inner model - this means $V\not=L$, since $L$ has no proper inner models.

---

The above shows that making $M$ too small can prevent an embedding from $V$ into $M$. And, this is for very good intuitive reasons: in order to have an embedding of $V$ into $M$, $M$ must at least have all the basic large cardinal structure of $V$, and modest large cardinals can't exist in "too small" models.

Your question indicates that you're aware of the dual fact (the **Kunen inconsistency**), which states that we cannot have an elementary embedding of $V$ into $V$ - that is, making $M$ too big also poses a problem. So, what's the intuition behind this one?

Well, the Kunen inconsistency is a bit complicated. A good proof can be found on page 82 of http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/d.pdf (I prefer this to the exposition in Kanamori). Basically, the idea is this:

- Suppose we have $j: V\rightarrow V$ a nontrivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$.
- Then look at $\lambda=\sup\{j^n(\kappa): n\in\omega\}$. Note that $j(\lambda)=\lambda$, so this is the point where $j$ first "catches its tail".
- We can find a combinatorial gadget $f$ - an *$\omega$-Jonsson function* - on $\lambda$, which lets us nicely code the countable subsets of $\lambda$: $$f: ^\omega\lambda\rightarrow\lambda\quad\mbox{and for $y\subseteq \lambda, \vert y\vert=\lambda$, we have }f"{}^\omega y=\lambda.$$
- By elementarity, $j(f)$ is again $\omega$-Jonsson on $\lambda$. By nontriviality of $j$, $\kappa\not\in ran(j)$. But let $y=j"\lambda$. Then $\vert y\vert=\lambda$, so $\kappa\in j(f)"{}^\omega y$ via some $x\in {}^\omega y$. Let $\alpha_n$ be such that $x(n)=j(\alpha_n)$; then $$\kappa=j(f)(x)=j(f)(j(\langle \alpha_n\rangle_{n\in\omega}))=j(f(\langle \alpha_n\rangle_{n\in\omega})),$$ so $\kappa\in ran(j)$, contradiction.

The construction of an $\omega$-Jonsson function on an arbitrary infinite cardinal isn't hard; in fact, the proof takes only a couple paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

If $j: V \to L$ were elementary, there would be a measurable cardinal in $V$ hence $L$ would think so too. But Scott showed that this is impossible.